# Cross-compiling Valgrind for ppc32

Tags: c, valgrind, powerpc

I fail to cross configure/compile the current master of Valgrind in a docker container with an SDK that was created with Yocto/Bitbake. I found a similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514706/cross-compiling-valgrind-for-arm) and modified the configure call to match my toolchain.

This is the configure command I currently use:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-poky-linux-
./configure --target=powerpc-poky-linux \
              --host=powerpc-poky-linux \
              CFLAGS=-static \
              CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc \
              CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp \
              CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ \
              LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld \
              AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
```

It gives me the following output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for powerpc-poky-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for powerpc-poky-linux-gcc... powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And the content of the log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Valgrind configure 3.20.0.GIT, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --target=powerpc-poky-linux --host=powerpc-poky-linux CFLAGS=-static CC=powerpc-poky-linux-gcc CPP=powerpc-poky-linux-cpp CXX=powerpc-poky-linux-g++ LD=powerpc-poky-linux-ld AR=powerpc-poky-linux-ar

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = 213ae115b0d8
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.10.0-14-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2856: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2924: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2935: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2990: result: yes
configure:3049: checking for powerpc-poky-linux-strip
configure:3079: result: no
configure:3089: checking for strip
configure:3105: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:3116: result: strip
configure:3141: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3180: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3187: checking for gawk
configure:3217: result: no
configure:3187: checking for mawk
configure:3203: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3214: result: mawk
configure:3225: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3247: result: yes
configure:3276: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3293: result: yes
configure:3421: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3430: result: no
configure:3455: checking whether ln -s works
configure:3459: result: yes
configure:3474: checking for powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
configure:3501: result: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
configure:3770: checking for C compiler version
configure:3779: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc --version >&5
./configure: line 3781: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3790: $? = 127
configure:3779: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -v >&5
./configure: line 3781: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3790: $? = 127
configure:3779: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -V >&5
./configure: line 3781: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3790: $? = 127
configure:3779: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3781: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3790: $? = 127
configure:3810: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3832: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -static   conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3834: powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: command not found
configure:3836: $? = 127
configure:3874: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Valgrind"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "valgrind"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Valgrind 3.20.0.GIT"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "valgrind"
| #define VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3879: error: in `/home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind':
configure:3881: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_AR_set=set
ac_cv_env_AR_value=powerpc-poky-linux-ar
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-static
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=powerpc-poky-linux-cpp
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=powerpc-poky-linux-g++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LTO_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_LTO_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_LTO_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_LTO_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=powerpc-poky-linux
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=powerpc-poky-linux
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR='powerpc-poky-linux-ar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='mawk'
BOOST_CFLAGS=''
BOOST_LIBS=''
BUILD_ADDR32_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_ADDR32_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_ADX_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_ADX_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_ARMV81_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_ARMV81_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_ARMV82_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_ARMV82_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_ARMV8_CRC_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_ARMV8_CRC_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_AVX2_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_AVX2_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_AVX_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_AVX_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_BMI_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_BMI_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_DFP_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_DFP_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_F16C_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_F16C_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_FMA4_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_FMA4_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_FMA_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_FMA_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_IFUNC_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_IFUNC_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_LOOPNEL_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_LOOPNEL_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_LZCNT_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_LZCNT_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_MOVBE_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_MOVBE_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPIWRAP_PRI_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPIWRAP_PRI_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPIWRAP_SEC_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPIWRAP_SEC_TRUE=''
BUILD_MPX_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_MPX_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_PCLMULQDQ_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_PCLMULQDQ_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_RDRAND_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_RDRAND_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_RDSEED_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_RDSEED_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_SSE3_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_SSE3_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_SSE42_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_SSE42_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_SSSE3_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_SSSE3_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_TSX_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_TSX_TESTS_TRUE=''
BUILD_VPCLMULQDQ_TESTS_FALSE=''
BUILD_VPCLMULQDQ_TESTS_TRUE=''
CC='powerpc-poky-linux-gcc'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-static'
CFLAGS_MPI=''
COMPILER_IS_CLANG_FALSE=''
COMPILER_IS_CLANG_TRUE=''
COMPILER_IS_ICC_FALSE=''
COMPILER_IS_ICC_TRUE=''
CPP='powerpc-poky-linux-cpp'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='powerpc-poky-linux-g++'
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXX_CAN_INCLUDE_CONDITION_VARIABLE_HEADER_FALSE=''
CXX_CAN_INCLUDE_CONDITION_VARIABLE_HEADER_TRUE=''
CXX_CAN_INCLUDE_THREAD_HEADER_FALSE=''
CXX_CAN_INCLUDE_THREAD_HEADER_TRUE=''
CXX_CAN_USE_SHARED_TIMED_MUTEX_FALSE=''
CXX_CAN_USE_SHARED_TIMED_MUTEX_TRUE=''
CXX_CAN_USE_TIMED_MUTEX_FALSE=''
CXX_CAN_USE_TIMED_MUTEX_TRUE=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFAULT_SUPP=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DIFF=''
DIS_PATH=''
DWARF4_FALSE=''
DWARF4_TRUE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_LINUX_TICKET_LOCK_PRIMARY_FALSE=''
ENABLE_LINUX_TICKET_LOCK_PRIMARY_TRUE=''
ENABLE_LINUX_TICKET_LOCK_SECONDARY_FALSE=''
ENABLE_LINUX_TICKET_LOCK_SECONDARY_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
FLAG_FALIGNED_NEW=''
FLAG_FINLINE_FUNCTIONS=''
FLAG_FNO_IPA_ICF=''
FLAG_FNO_STACK_PROTECTOR=''
FLAG_FSANITIZE=''
FLAG_FSIZED_DEALLOCATION=''
FLAG_M32=''
FLAG_M64=''
FLAG_MLONG_DOUBLE_128=''
FLAG_MMMX=''
FLAG_MSA=''
FLAG_MSSE=''
FLAG_NO_BUILD_ID=''
FLAG_NO_PIE=''
FLAG_OCTEON2=''
FLAG_OCTEON=''
FLAG_PIE=''
FLAG_T_TEXT=''
FLAG_UNLIMITED_INLINE_UNIT_GROWTH=''
FLAG_W_CAST_ALIGN=''
FLAG_W_CAST_QUAL=''
FLAG_W_EMPTY_BODY=''
FLAG_W_ENUM_CONVERSION=''
FLAG_W_EXTRA=''
FLAG_W_FORMAT=''
FLAG_W_FORMAT_SECURITY=''
FLAG_W_FORMAT_SIGNEDNESS=''
FLAG_W_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS=''
FLAG_W_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH=''
FLAG_W_LOGICAL_OP=''
FLAG_W_MISSING_PARAMETER_TYPE=''
FLAG_W_NO_EXPANSION_TO_DEFINED=''
FLAG_W_NO_INFINITE_RECURSION=''
FLAG_W_NO_MEMSET_TRANSPOSED_ARGS=''
FLAG_W_NO_MISMATCHED_NEW_DELETE=''
FLAG_W_NO_NONNULL=''
FLAG_W_NO_OVERFLOW=''
FLAG_W_NO_POINTER_SIGN=''
FLAG_W_NO_STATIC_LOCAL_IN_INLINE=''
FLAG_W_NO_UNINITIALIZED=''
FLAG_W_NO_UNUSED_FUNCTION=''
FLAG_W_OLD_STYLE_DECLARATION=''
FLAG_W_WRITE_STRINGS=''
FREEBSD_VERS_13_PLUS_FALSE=''
FREEBSD_VERS_13_PLUS_TRUE=''
GDB=''
GLIBC_LIBC_PATH=''
GLIBC_LIBPTHREAD_PATH=''
GLIBC_VERSION=''
GREP=''
GZ_ZLIB_FALSE=''
GZ_ZLIB_GNU_FALSE=''
GZ_ZLIB_GNU_TRUE=''
GZ_ZLIB_TRUE=''
HAS_ALTIVEC_FALSE=''
HAS_ALTIVEC_TRUE=''
HAS_DARN_FALSE=''
HAS_DARN_TRUE=''
HAS_DFP_FALSE=''
HAS_DFP_TRUE=''
HAS_ISA_2_05_FALSE=''
HAS_ISA_2_05_TRUE=''
HAS_ISA_2_06_FALSE=''
HAS_ISA_2_06_TRUE=''
HAS_ISA_2_07_FALSE=''
HAS_ISA_2_07_TRUE=''
HAS_ISA_3_00_FALSE=''
HAS_ISA_3_00_TRUE=''
HAS_ISA_3_1_FALSE=''
HAS_ISA_3_1_TRUE=''
HAS_MLONG_DOUBLE_128_FALSE=''
HAS_MLONG_DOUBLE_128_TRUE=''
HAS_VSX_FALSE=''
HAS_VSX_TRUE=''
HAS_XSCVHPDP_FALSE=''
HAS_XSCVHPDP_TRUE=''
HAVE_ALIGNED_CXX_ALLOC_FALSE=''
HAVE_ALIGNED_CXX_ALLOC_TRUE=''
HAVE_ANSI_FALSE=''
HAVE_ANSI_TRUE=''
HAVE_ASM_CONSTRAINT_P_FALSE=''
HAVE_ASM_CONSTRAINT_P_TRUE=''
HAVE_AT_FDCWD_FALSE=''
HAVE_AT_FDCWD_TRUE=''
HAVE_BOOST_1_35_FALSE=''
HAVE_BOOST_1_35_TRUE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC64_FALSE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC64_TRUE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_CXX_FALSE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_CXX_TRUE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_FALSE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_SECONDARY_FALSE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_SECONDARY_TRUE=''
HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC_TRUE=''
HAVE_COPY_FILE_RANGE_FALSE=''
HAVE_COPY_FILE_RANGE_TRUE=''
HAVE_DLINFO_RTLD_DI_TLS_MODID_FALSE=''
HAVE_DLINFO_RTLD_DI_TLS_MODID_TRUE=''
HAVE_FSIZED_DEALLOCATION_FALSE=''
HAVE_FSIZED_DEALLOCATION_TRUE=''
HAVE_GNU_STPNCPY_FALSE=''
HAVE_GNU_STPNCPY_TRUE=''
HAVE_MEMFD_CREATE_FALSE=''
HAVE_MEMFD_CREATE_TRUE=''
HAVE_NESTED_FUNCTIONS_FALSE=''
HAVE_NESTED_FUNCTIONS_TRUE=''
HAVE_NR_MEMBARRIER_FALSE=''
HAVE_NR_MEMBARRIER_TRUE=''
HAVE_OPENMP_FALSE=''
HAVE_OPENMP_TRUE=''
HAVE_PREADV2_PWRITEV2_FALSE=''
HAVE_PREADV2_PWRITEV2_TRUE=''
HAVE_PREADV_PWRITEV_FALSE=''
HAVE_PREADV_PWRITEV_TRUE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_BARRIER_FALSE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_BARRIER_TRUE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_CREATE_GLIBC_2_0_FALSE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_CREATE_GLIBC_2_0_TRUE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMEDLOCK_FALSE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMEDLOCK_TRUE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP_FALSE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_SETNAME_NP_TRUE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_SPINLOCK_FALSE=''
HAVE_PTHREAD_SPINLOCK_TRUE=''
HAVE_SETCONTEXT_FALSE=''
HAVE_SETCONTEXT_TRUE=''
HAVE_SHARED_POINTER_ANNOTATION_FALSE=''
HAVE_SHARED_POINTER_ANNOTATION_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWAPCONTEXT_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWAPCONTEXT_TRUE=''
HWCAP_HAS_ALTIVEC=''
HWCAP_HAS_DFP=''
HWCAP_HAS_HTM=''
HWCAP_HAS_ISA_2_05=''
HWCAP_HAS_ISA_2_06=''
HWCAP_HAS_ISA_2_07=''
HWCAP_HAS_ISA_3_00=''
HWCAP_HAS_ISA_3_1=''
HWCAP_HAS_MMA=''
HWCAP_HAS_VSX=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_MPI=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIB_UBSAN=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
LTO_AR=''
LTO_CFLAGS=''
LTO_RANLIB=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/missing makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MPI_CC=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='valgrind'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net'
PACKAGE_NAME='Valgrind'
PACKAGE_STRING='Valgrind 3.20.0.GIT'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='valgrind'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.20.0.GIT'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PREFERRED_STACK_BOUNDARY_2=''
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SOLARIS_AUDITON_STAT_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_AUDITON_STAT_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_EXECVE_SYSCALL_TAKES_FLAGS_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_EXECVE_SYSCALL_TAKES_FLAGS_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_FREALPATHAT_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_FREALPATHAT_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_GETHRT_FASTTRAP_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_GETHRT_FASTTRAP_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_GETRANDOM_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_GETRANDOM_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_GETZONEOFFSET_FASTTRAP_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_GETZONEOFFSET_FASTTRAP_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_NAME_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_NAME_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_SIGQUEUE_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_SIGQUEUE_SYSCALL_TAKES_PID_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_SIGQUEUE_SYSCALL_TAKES_PID_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_LWP_SIGQUEUE_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_MODCTL_MODNVL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_MODCTL_MODNVL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_NSCD_DOOR_SYSTEM_VOLATILE_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_NSCD_DOOR_SYSTEM_VOLATILE_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_OLD_SYSCALLS_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_OLD_SYSCALLS_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_PROC_CMDLINE_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_PROC_CMDLINE_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_PRXREGSET_T_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_PRXREGSET_T_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_PSET_GET_NAME_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_PSET_GET_NAME_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_RESERVE_SYSSTAT_ADDR_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_RESERVE_SYSSTAT_ADDR_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_RESERVE_SYSSTAT_ZONE_ADDR_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_RESERVE_SYSSTAT_ZONE_ADDR_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_SHM_NEW_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_SHM_NEW_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_SPAWN_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_SPAWN_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_SUN_STUDIO_AS_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_SUN_STUDIO_AS_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_SYSTEM_STATS_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_SYSTEM_STATS_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_TNDB_GET_TNIP_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_TNDB_GET_TNIP_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_TSOL_CLEARANCE_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_TSOL_CLEARANCE_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_UNDEF_LARGESOURCE=''
SOLARIS_UTIMENSAT_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_UTIMENSAT_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_UTIMESYS_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_UTIMESYS_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_UUIDSYS_SYSCALL_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_UUIDSYS_SYSCALL_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_XPG_SYMBOLS_PRESENT_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_XPG_SYMBOLS_PRESENT_TRUE=''
SOLARIS_ZONE_DEFUNCT_FALSE=''
SOLARIS_ZONE_DEFUNCT_TRUE=''
STRIP='strip'
SUPPORTS_HTM_FALSE=''
SUPPORTS_HTM_TRUE=''
VALT_LOAD_ADDRESS_PRI=''
VALT_LOAD_ADDRESS_SEC=''
VERSION='3.20.0.GIT'
VGCONF_ABI=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_AMD64_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_AMD64_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_ARM64_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_ARM64_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_ARM_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_ARM_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_MIPS32_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_MIPS32_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_MIPS64_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_MIPS64_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_NANOMIPS_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_NANOMIPS_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_PPC32_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_PPC32_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_PPC64_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_PPC64_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_S390X_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_S390X_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_X86_FALSE=''
VGCONF_ARCHS_INCLUDE_X86_TRUE=''
VGCONF_ARCH_PRI=''
VGCONF_ARCH_SEC=''
VGCONF_HAVE_ABI_FALSE=''
VGCONF_HAVE_ABI_TRUE=''
VGCONF_HAVE_PLATFORM_SEC_FALSE=''
VGCONF_HAVE_PLATFORM_SEC_TRUE=''
VGCONF_OS=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_DARWIN_FALSE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_DARWIN_OR_FREEBSD_FALSE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_DARWIN_OR_FREEBSD_TRUE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_DARWIN_TRUE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_FREEBSD_FALSE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_FREEBSD_TRUE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_SOLARIS_FALSE=''
VGCONF_OS_IS_SOLARIS_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_DARWIN_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_DARWIN_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_FREEBSD_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_FREEBSD_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_SOLARIS_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_AMD64_SOLARIS_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_ARM64_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_ARM64_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_ARM_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_ARM_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_MIPS32_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_MIPS32_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_MIPS64_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_MIPS64_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_NANOMIPS_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_NANOMIPS_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC32_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC32_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC64BE_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC64BE_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC64LE_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_PPC64LE_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_S390X_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_S390X_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_DARWIN_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_DARWIN_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_FREEBSD_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_FREEBSD_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_LINUX_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_LINUX_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_SOLARIS_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORMS_INCLUDE_X86_SOLARIS_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATFORM_PRI_CAPS=''
VGCONF_PLATFORM_SEC_CAPS=''
VGCONF_PLATVARIANT=''
VGCONF_PLATVARIANT_IS_ANDROID_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATVARIANT_IS_ANDROID_TRUE=''
VGCONF_PLATVARIANT_IS_VANILLA_FALSE=''
VGCONF_PLATVARIANT_IS_VANILLA_TRUE=''
VG_DATE='?? Oct 2022'
VG_TMPDIR=''
VG_VER_MAJOR='3'
VG_VER_MINOR='20'
XCODE_DIR=''
XCRUN=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='powerpc-poky-linux'
host_alias='powerpc-poky-linux'
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='powerpc-poky-linux'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Valgrind"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "valgrind"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Valgrind 3.20.0.GIT"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "valgrind"
#define VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"

configure: exit 77
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit:

When I use an absolute path for gcc the compiler version check succeeds, but the test compile still fails:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Valgrind configure 3.20.0.GIT, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --target=powerpc-poky-linux --host=powerpc-poky-linux --prefix=/opt/valgrind CFLAGS=-static CC=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc CPP=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-cpp CXX=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-g++ LD=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-ld AR=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-ar

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = 2766f157796f
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.10.0-14-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 5.10.113-1 (2022-04-29)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2856: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2924: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2935: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2990: result: yes
configure:3049: checking for powerpc-poky-linux-strip
configure:3079: result: no
configure:3089: checking for strip
configure:3105: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:3116: result: strip
configure:3141: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3180: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3187: checking for gawk
configure:3217: result: no
configure:3187: checking for mawk
configure:3203: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3214: result: mawk
configure:3225: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3247: result: yes
configure:3276: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3293: result: yes
configure:3421: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3430: result: no
configure:3455: checking whether ln -s works
configure:3459: result: yes
configure:3474: checking for powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
configure:3501: result: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
configure:3770: checking for C compiler version
configure:3779: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc --version >&5
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3790: $? = 0
configure:3779: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: powerpc-poky-linux
Configured with: ../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-9.3.0-r0/gcc-9.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-siemens-linux --target=powerpc-poky-linux --prefix=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr --bindir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux --sbindir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux --libexecdir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux --datadir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/com --localstatedir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/var --libdir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/lib/powerpc-poky-linux --includedir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/include --infodir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/opt/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/xxxx/git/CP61850/ps_cp61850-bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-siemens-linux/gcc-cross-canadian-powerpc/9.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --enable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=powerpc-poky-linux- --without-local-prefix --disable-install-libiberty --enable-lto --disable-libssp --enable-libitm --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --with-cloog=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --without-isl --with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/9.3.0 --with-build-time-tools=/home/xxxx/git/CP61850/ps_cp61850-bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-siemens-linux/gcc-cross-canadian-powerpc/9.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/powerpc-poky-linux/bin --with-sysroot=/not/exist --with-build-sysroot=/home/xxxx/git/CP61850/ps_cp61850-bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-siemens-linux/gcc-cross-canadian-powerpc/9.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot --enable-secureplt --enable-targets=powerpc64 --enable-poison-system-directories --disable-static --enable-nls --with-glibc-version=2.28 --enable-initfini-array --enable-__cxa_atexit
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC) 
configure:3790: $? = 0
configure:3779: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -V >&5
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3790: $? = 1
configure:3779: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -qversion >&5
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3790: $? = 1
configure:3810: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3832: /cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-poky-linux/powerpc-poky-linux-gcc -static   conftest.c  >&5
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginT.o: No such file or directory
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_eh
/cp61850-sdk/sysroots/x86_64-siemens-linux/usr/libexec/powerpc-poky-linux/gcc/powerpc-poky-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3836: $? = 1
configure:3874: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Valgrind"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "valgrind"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Valgrind 3.20.0.GIT"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "valgrind-users@lists.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "valgrind"
| #define VERSION "3.20.0.GIT"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3879: error: in `/home/xxxx/git/ext/valgrind':
configure:3881: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

...
```

Comment: Can you execute `powerpc-poky-linux-gcc` manually?

Comment: Yes. `powerpc-poky-linux-gcc --version
powerpc-poky-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
`

Comment: Does it work if you specify the absolute path in CC ?

Comment: @PaulFloyd No, see Edit.